# Append data from multiple forms to store all records in json

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, forms

I want to continually append form data to a json object

Example of when I submit my form the data looks like this

```
{"firstName":"jack", "lastName":"miller"}
```

However - I need to keep appending that data with a new form submitted so that I can store all the form data

I would expect that the append of this would be json format so above would have those values and comma separated for each "record"

```
captureForm = (event) => {

    const data = new FormData(event.target);

    let medicationJSON = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(data));

    allFormData += "," + medicationJSON;
}
```

Obviously above is more pseudo code , but I don't want to manually add a comma as then its a hack, with a starting comma that I would need to remove.

How can I keep submitting new form and append the data ?

I am using React - but for this , It doesn't seem to be anything for React to be involved with...

Here is a jsfiddle:    Here is a fiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/ua9y185t/     `m` is set to parse that fordata , i tried various combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form data append documentation [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

```
data.append("firstName", "jack");
data.append("lastName", "miller");
data.append(allData);
```

The `append()` method of the `FormData` interface appends a new value onto an existing key inside a `FormData object`, or adds the key if it does not already exist.

Comment: but that doesn't such my code at all - that is from mozilla documentation

Comment: Isn't append jquery though?

Comment: Check my update, @JeremyMiller it is not Jquery, it will do what you are trying to do. Its based off your `new FormData` just call that variable names method of append.

Comment: Here is a fiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/ua9y185t/     `m` is the data from the formdata it doesn't like the format

Answer (score 0):

You could make `allFormData` an array and keep pushing data to it.
And when you want to send it use `allFormData.join(',')`

Comment: so after i do the join,  then how do i add the extra data?

Comment: also,   allFormData.join(',')     `join is not function`  even if i remove json.stringify

Comment: i mentioned that you need to make `allFormData` an array first. Then you only use `.join` when you want to use it as a string.

Comment: Here is a fiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/ua9y185t/     `m` is the data from the formdata it doesn't like the format

Comment: @JeremyMiller please post how you would like the allData object to look after you have clicked submit on both forms